# Array: Cannot read property '0' of null

Tags: node.js, regex

I am trying to access the first value of the return value of str.match and get an error. `console.log(match)` works and returns an array but `console.log(match[0])` does not.

Input string:

```
.test {
    color: black;
    background: url(asd.jpg)
}
```

Function:

```
const parseFiles = (data) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(/url\(.*?\)/);
    const match = data.match(regex);
    console.log(match);
};
```

Output:

```
[ 'url(asd.jpg)',
  index: 38,
  input: '.test {\n  color: black;\n  background: url(asd.jpg); }\n' ]
```

Error when using `console.log(match[0])` instead:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at parseFiles (F:\10\dev\PhpStormProjects\sassmann\lib\index.js:36:22)
    at Object.sass.render [as callback] (F:\10\dev\PhpStormProjects\sassmann\lib\index.js:29:9)
    at options.success (F:\10\dev\PhpStormProjects\sassmann\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:308:32)
```

`node -v` v9.2.1

Have I overlooked something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

> If the string matches the expression, it will return an Array
>   containing the entire matched string as the first element, followed by
>   any results captured in parentheses. **If there were no matches, null is
>   returned.**

Comment: I use the same input which contains a match. As stated, `console.log(match)` works and `console.log(match[0])` throws. I want To access the first value of the returned array.

Comment: [Are you sure?](https://jsfiddle.net/JakeballBase/9xhzreLr/5/) Your example parses for me, but there is a chance that you are passing something that does not match into your method. You should perform a `null` check before trying to access the result.

Comment: forgot the null check and ran it against two inputs instead of just one of which one did not match... Thank you.